# Как избегать ошибок при использовании функции load_file()?

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

Пользуюсь для парсинга библиотекой *Simple HTML DOM*. Функция `load_file()` работает, как известно, на основе `file_get_contentns()`.

Есть страницы магазина, которые крайне медленно грузятся (просто какой-то баговый раздел), в результате чего появляется предупреждение:

```
Failed to Open Stream: HTTP request failed.
```

Само по себе предупреждение - не проблема, пусть будет. Просто к пустому объекту нельзя применять `find()`, там уже "фатал".

Как грамотно проверить на валидность загруженное содержимое `$html`?

Я пробовал такой вариант:

```
foreach ($item as $link) {
    $html = new simple_html_dom;
    $html -> load_file($link);
    if ($html->root !== NULL) { парсим }
}
```

`root` - это свойство объекта, которое равно `NULL`, если объект пуст. До первой ошибки всё работает адекватно, но как только сталкивается с ошибкой, он логично пропускает эту страницу, переходит к следующей странице, но уже независимо от характера этой страницы (получилось загрузить или нет - это видно по предупреждениям) отказывается парсить.

В чем может быть дело?

Comment: Какие выскакивают предупреждения после `Failed to Open Stream: HTTP request failed.` ?

Comment: Если вы хотите уточнить какой фатал, то он ругается, что я обращаюсь функцией find() к non-object.